# Codeigniter remove "(" in join clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting a problem in a join clause... this is my code:

```
$this->db->select("users.id, users.first_name, users.second_name")->from("users");
$this->db->join("users_groups", "users_groups.user_id=users.id AND (users_groups.group_id=".$this->config->item("admin_group")." OR users_groups.group_id=".$this->config->item("admin_location_group")." OR users_groups.group_id=".$this->config->item("employee_group").")", "INNER");
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

And what it produce is this:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`second_name` FROM `users` INNER JOIN `users_groups` ON `users_groups`.`user_id`=`users`.`id` AND `users_groups`.`group_id`=1 OR `users_groups`.`group_id`=8 OR `users_groups`.`group_id`=4)
```

A parenthesis before *`users_groups`.`group_id`=1* is removed... any idea about why??

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that this query has a fourth optional arguement that if you set to true will not escape the data, that might stop the parser removing the brackets (and stop the escaping). But this is peculiar, certainly. I cannot see anything wrong with the query itself.

Comment: Is your query means  `WHERE users_groups.group_id=1 OR users_groups.group_id=8 OR users_groups.group_id=4` after `AND` ?

Comment: Thanks @PaulD... the fourth parameter is the solution (if you put as solution I´ll mark as the good one).

Comment: Thanks @Benyi... I knew that I can use a where clause, but I prefer use the filter in the join.

Comment: If so, you can use `$this->db->where()` clause. It would be more clearly. With `$this->db->where()`, you can also use `$this->db->group_start();` and `$this->db->group_end()` query builders. See the reference [Query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Benyi I knew... but insert this "filter" in the join is, usually, faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Join query has a fourth optional arguement that if you set to true will not escape the data, that will stop the parser removing the brackets (and stop the escaping).

From the Docs:

> join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = NULL]])
>       Parameters:
>
> ```
>     $table (string) – Table name to join
>     $cond (string) – The JOIN ON condition
>     $type (string) – The JOIN type
>     $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
> CI_DB_query_builder instance (method chaining)
> ```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::join